# Check for linebreaks in textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery, counter, line-breaks

I want something like a counter for every linebreaks in a textarea. This is used when uploading a huge number of webbanners, so i need a simple counter for how many a user has added. Right now the counter works only when a user presses a link with a special bannersize.

This is my code as it is right now:

```
var i = 0;

$('.size').click(function(){
$('#total-number').text(i++);
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Utilize the String [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function...

```
var text = $('#total-number').text();
var eachLine = text.split('\n');

alert('Lines found: ' + eachLine.length);

for(var i = 0, l = eachLine.length; i < l; i++) {
  alert('Line ' + (i+1) + ': ' + eachLine[i]);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `text()` function omit line breaks?

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions, your problem can be solved like this (searching the textarea for the new line character "\n")):

```
//assuming $('#total-number') is your textarea element
var text = $('#total-number').val();
// look for any "\n" occurences
var matches = text.match(/\n/g);
// count them, if there are any
var breaks = matches ? matches.length : 0;
```

`breaks` variable now contains number of line breaks in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Search the textarea for "\n".

To be certain, do a regex search for pattern "\\n" and count the matches array, that will be the linebreak count.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you mannualy press enter, but is there a way of count the line breaks that textarea creates when you copy-paste data on it? I mean, if you define a width for a textarea and then paste some text, it will create linebreaks...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a single-line string that wraps. A line break, if I'm not mistaken, is created when one presses Enter or Shift+Enter.